# Mystery user receiving emails for admin changes?

Tags: business-catalyst

*This is not a development question but I couldn't find other sites in the network with a tag for [business-catalyst](/questions/tagged/business-catalyst).*

I inherited a website hosted on Adobe Business Catalyst.  Currently there are 3 admin users, all emails I recognize.  I made some changes to a user role and received an email that went to the 3 admins (including myself) as well as an additional gmail address for someone I do not know. (I think it's a former employee)  I can't find reference to this address anywhere in the admin portal.

I know next to nothing about BC but this is a serious concern.  How can I ensure this person has no access to our site?

Answer (score 1):

Business Catalyst uses notification Workflows which can be configured to trigger on things such as Web Form submission, changes to a page and more.

Under Site Settings / Manage Workflows, open each workflow and under the "Add steps to this workflow" tab; there is an option to also send notifications to additional emails (other than system administrators).

Hopefully inside one of these you'll find the former employee email addresses to be removed.